# PyTorch multiprocessing: are ACER implementations moving gradients correctly?

Tags: python, multithreading, pytorch, python-multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning

I am implementing the ACER architecture, which performs asynchronous parameter update as A3C. Looking at existing PyTorch implementations, I often see the parameter update performed as

```py
# Transfers gradients from thread-specific model to shared model
def _transfer_grads_to_shared_model(model, shared_model):
  for param, shared_param in zip(model.parameters(), shared_model.parameters()):
    if shared_param.grad is not None:
      return
    shared_param._grad = param.grad
```

I understand that if shared_param.grad is not None it means another thread added a gradient to the model, thus we return to not overwrite it.

My questions are:

- This way we are "throwing away" some of the gradients computed, am I right?
- Why don't we use a lock mechanism when updating the shared model parameters? It would avoid two threads updating the parameters at the same time. Since the threads spend most of their time performing steps in the environment and updating their local models, adding a lock on the shared model update may have a negligible impact on the performances. Am I right on this? If yes, why isn't it done in practice?
- What happens if a thread calls `optimizer.step()` on the shared_model while another thread is copying gradients to it?

Another implementation I found does it this way:

```py
def copy_gradients_from(model, shared_model):
  for shared_parameter, parameter in zip(shared_model.parameters(), model.parameters()):
    shared_parameter._grad = parameter.grad
```

which does not check for existing gradients, and is also called without any `Lock` mechanism.